# Cannot change Button background after applying BottomSheetDialogFragment background

Tags: android, android-studio, android-bottomsheetdialog, bottomsheetdialogfragment

I needed rounded corners on my BottomSheetDialogFragment so I applied a custom drawable as its background. But after applying a custom background the button on the BottomSheet is not accepting a custom background. It just displays a white background. backgroundTint works fine and changes the color of the button.

themes.xml :

```
<style name="AppBottomSheetDialogTheme"
    parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/AppModalStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="AppModalStyle"
    parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/add_new_bg</item>
</style>
```

add_new_bg.xml :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid
        android:color="@color/background"/>
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="40dp"
        android:topRightRadius="40dp"/>
</shape>
```

BottomSheetDialogFragment code :

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.AppBottomSheetDialogTheme);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

1. if your main theme is **Theme.AppCompat.Light** :

example :

```
<style name="Theme.YourAppName" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

and your button is :

```
<Button <------ material button type
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/buttonTheme" <---- add this
    android:text="MyButton"/>
```

add this in your themes.xml below main theme

```
    <style name="buttonTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
       <item name="theme">@style/buttonTheme</item>
       <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
       <item name="android:background">@color/black</item>
   </style>
```

2. if your main theme is : **Theme.MaterialComponents**

example :

```
<style name="Theme.RecyclerView" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

but your button use :

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton <<<<--- appcompact button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/buttonTheme" 
        android:text="MyButton"/>
```

then add :

```
<style name="buttonTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="theme">@style/buttonTheme</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

themes with button type must be same type.

let me know if this works for you.. and upvote it :)

Comment: Not working :-(. The button still has a white background

Comment: Check my new answer

Comment: The background is still not changing. If i use Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar as my parent theme the button is white. But its normal when i use Theme.AppCompat.Light.

Comment: yeah, so use option no 2

Answer (score 0):

See if you want to apply only background color to a button in bottom sheet
Just use background tint "YOUR_COLOR_CODE" in your code